# How do I tether internet from my iPhone?

Tags: 11.10, iphone, tethering

I'm trying to USB tether Internet from my iPhone 4 and when I connect the phone, it will appear as a wired connection but my pc will never establish a connection with the phone.
I've recently installed Ubuntu 11.10 but have yet to perform any updates.
Is there any configuration changes I need to make or install any third party apps to get this going?

Answer (score 1):

There is a package in the Ubuntu Software Centre that allows you to USB tether to your iPhone. You can find the package here:

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/ipheth-utils/

Answer (score 0):

You can always download the sources and compile it: http://blueman-project.org/downloads.html

**Building from source:**

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc
make
sudo make install
```

**Build dependencies:**

```
glib2.0
gtk >= 2.14
startup-notification
python-gobject
bluez >= 4.0
intltool
python2.[5,6]-dev
pyrex >= 0.9.8.0
```

**Runtime dependencies:**

```
python >= 2.5
dbus
bluez >= 4.25
obex-data-server >= 0.4.3
python-notify
python-gtk2 >= 2.12
python-gconf  (optional)
python-dbus
python-gobject
policykit-1  (optional)
libpulse, libpulse-mainloop-glib >=0.9.15  (optional)
notification-daemon or any other libnotify compatible engine.
```

Note to package maintainers, you can disable runtime dependency checking by using `--with-no-runtime-deps-check` configure flag.

---

**Bzr repository:**

Bzr web: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~blueman/blueman/trunk/files

```
bzr branch lp:blueman
```

to get the latest code.

Comment: Does this source contain USB tethering? In the tutorial it's only for Bluetooth tethering.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following:

```
$ gksu gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

... then add to the end:

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu natty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pmcenery/ppa/ubuntu natty main
```

Save and close the file and then run:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils ipheth-dkms
```

then update your iphone to 5.1

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for **ubuntu 14.04 LTS**

To get **iPhone 4 USB tethering**, do the following on a terminal:

1. `sudo apt-get install ipheth-utils`
2. `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-dev`
3. `sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils`
4. `sudo apt-get install gtkpod`

It works for me on my two machines runnning **ubuntu 14.04 LTS**