# iPhone USB Tethering with 11.10

Tags: 11.10, iphone, tethering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tether internet from my iPhone?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89949/how-do-i-tether-internet-from-my-iphone)

I found a solution: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/iphone-tethering-on-ubuntu-9-10-karmic.html
but this PPA is not available for Oneric.

How can I make tethering with my iPhone on Ubuntu Oneric?

Comment: See the answer in another thread: [question]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/89949